# How to add a custom Rules "action" in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-rules

I'm using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module in Drupal 7, and I tried to add a new Rules "Action"

I followed the steps described in [How to create an custom rule action using hook_rules_action_info?](http://www.zyxware.com/articles/5213/how-to-create-an-custom-rule-action-using-hook-rules-action-info) to create a custom rule action using `hook_rules_action_info`:

- I tried to create a sample file `(save_nid.rules.inc)` in the folder `/rules/module/`.
- And I also tried to create a `module` folder in `/site/all/module/save_nid/`.

My code in `save_nid.rules.inc` looks like so:

```
  function rules_save_nid_action_info() {
      return array(
      'save_nid_action' => array(
        'label' => t('Custom Action'),
        'parameter' => array(
          'param1' => array(
            'type' => 'int',
            'label' => t('Parameter Label'),
          ),
          'param2' => array(
            'type' => 'commerce_order',
            'label' => t('Parameter Label2'),
          ),
        ),
        'configurable' => FALSE,
        'group' => t('ABC Custom module action'),
        'callbacks' => array(
          'execute' => 'abc_custom_action',
        ),
      ),
  }
```

After I cleared the Drupal cache, I didn't see my "custom rule" in the list.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the machine name of your custom module seems to be `save_nid`.

So if you want to use `hook_rules_action_info` in your module, your function needs to be named `save_nid_rules_action_info`, instead of  `rules_save_nid_action_info`.

Not sure if it is the "only" problem why you can't get it to work, but at least it is "a" problem you need to address.

PS: make sure to save that custom coding in your custom module's folder (in `/site/all/module/save_nid/`).